# Can not login on Debian

Tags: debian, login, mate-desktop

After running once `startx` command in terminal i can not login as user anymore to my normal desktop. It still works as root. I am using the Mate desktop environment. Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cd ~
sudo chown username:groupname .Xauthority
```

You must have restarted X server as a root user and thus the file .`Xauthority` which was owned by the user, now got owned by root.

Try giving back the ownership as suggested.

Comment: how can i find out the groupname? `groups amir` gives me :
amir : amir cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev lpadmin scanner bluetooth

Comment: use grep <username> /etc/groups to get your username